# Use tf.nn.l2_loss on a collection of differently shaped vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calcualte the l2 loss over all my weights and biases in my neural network. Therefor I add all weights and biases to the 'tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES' and want to calculate the l2 loss with the in tensorflow defined function:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([inputDim, outputDim], stddev=0.1), name='W')
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([outputDim])/10, name='b')

tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, W)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, b)
...
```

and later in the code:

```
...
vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
l2_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(vars) * config.L2PENALTY
```

I get this error using the function on a network with 3 layers and couldn't find a solution to it:

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 't' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 4 with other shapes. for 'l2_loss/L2Loss/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [784,512], [512], [512,256], [256], [256,10], [10].
```

Comment: `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` is meant to hold scalar tensors with the regularization values, not the regularized tensors (that is, the L2 values, not the tensors for which it is computed). You can also use [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) with a `regularizer` parameter that will add the loss to the collection.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I didn't know 'tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES' expects scalar tensors. Using 'tf.get_variable' instead of 'tf.Variable' fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although tf.nn.l2_loss receives Tensor as its argument, you passed a list of Tensors to tf.nn.l2_loss. So the error message means l2_loss cannot convert the list to a Tensor.

We should calculate L2 loss like

```
vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
list_l2_loss = []
for v in vars:
    list_l2_loss.append(tf.nn.l2_loss(v))
total_l2_loss = tf.add_n(list_l2_loss)
```

*Adding Information*

You can add n-D Tensor to a collection by tf.add_to_collection. But tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES is the reserved name for regularizers created by tf.get_variable. So we should you an original name like "MyReguralizers".